# Построить точечный график

Tags: java, график

Какой самый простой способ построить точечный график при помощи Java?

Есть два массива данных, разделяю каждый из них на два для получения координат

```
//получение координат для построения графика
        double[] Xwords = new double[words.length];
        double[] Ywords = new double[words.length];
        //разделяем массив слов на два массива с координатами
        for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
                Xwords[i] = words[i][0];
                Ywords[i] = words[i][1];
        } 

        double[] Xdocs = new double[docs[0].length];
        double[] Ydocs = new double[docs[0].length];
        //разделяем массив термов на два массива с координатами
        for (int i=0; i<docs[0].length; i++){
                Xdocs[i] = docs[0][i];
                Ydocs[i] = docs[1][i];
        }
```

Какая библиотека позволит в пару строчек загнать эти данные в метод и получить обычный точечный график?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовала библиотеку JFreeChart, [здесь](https://www.boraji.com/jfreechart-scatter-chart-example) хороший пример

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать стандартный Java2D, то код, рисующий точечный график, может выглядеть, например, так:

```
public void drawDiagram(Graphics g, double[] x, double y[], double scaling, int height, Color color) {
  int lastX = 0, lastY = 0;

  g.setColor(color);

  for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   g.drawLine((int)(lastX * scaling), height - (int)(lastY * scaling),
           height - (int)(x[i] * scaling), (int)(y[i] * scaling));

   lastX = (int)x[i];
   lastY = (int)y[i];
  }
}
```

Где:

- `g` - графический контекст холста или изображения.
- `x` - массив с координатами `x`.
- `y` - массив с координатами `y`.
- `scaling` - множитель масштабирования.
- `height` - высота панели для рисования (также можно взять максимальную координату `y`).
- `color` - цвет линии.

Answer (score -1):

На `Canvas` рисовать. Взять `SurfaceView` и в методе `OnDraw()` отрисовать что нужно.